# How to Add new key and value to array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have two array, lets suppose have below value of array: "

```
var array1 = [
{Id: "809cd136-02c7-4cc8-b9de-04fd3359b265", Name: "testing"},
{Id: "609d3a78-8f7c-4843-acdb-2dcfc73c0d96", Name: "Delhi"},
{Id: "264d54cb-b104-48ed-91db-673327ae8d0e", Name: "rohit-auditor"},
{Id: "ce9691b3-dc55-4d30-baf4-7987c2b49b3e", Name: "test"},
{Id: "284e9e98-8ed7-4fb7-b09f-5d1f2a668b15", Name: "aman"}
]
```

and second array is :

```
var array2 = ["809cd136-02c7-4cc8-b9de-04fd3359b265", "609d3a78-8f7c-4843-acdb-2dcfc73c0d96"]
```

Now i want to add one new key value in array1 only in those object whose value is equal to array one. In other words in want to match both array and want to add "status = true" in those that is having equal value.

new key want to add is :

```
{status: true}
```

Now my new array should be:

```
[
{Id: "809cd136-02c7-4cc8-b9de-04fd3359b265", Name: "testing", status: true},
{Id: "609d3a78-8f7c-4843-acdb-2dcfc73c0d96", Name: "Delhi", status: true},
{Id: "264d54cb-b104-48ed-91db-673327ae8d0e", Name: "rohit-auditor"},
{Id: "ce9691b3-dc55-4d30-baf4-7987c2b49b3e", Name: "test"},
{Id: "284e9e98-8ed7-4fb7-b09f-5d1f2a668b15", Name: "aman"}
```

]

Hope you understand.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) like this:

```js
let array1=[{Id:"809cd136-02c7-4cc8-b9de-04fd3359b265",Name:"testing"},{Id:"609d3a78-8f7c-4843-acdb-2dcfc73c0d96",Name:"Delhi"},{Id:"264d54cb-b104-48ed-91db-673327ae8d0e",Name:"rohit-auditor"},{Id:"ce9691b3-dc55-4d30-baf4-7987c2b49b3e",Name:"test"},{Id:"284e9e98-8ed7-4fb7-b09f-5d1f2a668b15",Name:"aman"}],
    array2=["809cd136-02c7-4cc8-b9de-04fd3359b265","609d3a78-8f7c-4843-acdb-2dcfc73c0d96"]
    
array2.forEach(id => {
  let found = array1.find(a => a.Id === id);
  if(found)
    found.status = true
})

console.log(array1)
```

The `if` check is there to check if the `Id` in `array2` exists in `array1`. If every `Id` in `array2` exists in `array1`, you can simply change it to:

```
array1.find(a => a.Id === id).status = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to iterate and create a new array and then use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method to check the value present in the array2. Where use [ES6 spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to combine both objects.

```
var newArray = array1.map(o => array2.includes(o.Id) ? {...o,  ...add} : { ...add })
```

```js
var array1 = [{
    Id: "809cd136-02c7-4cc8-b9de-04fd3359b265",
    Name: "testing"
  },
  {
    Id: "609d3a78-8f7c-4843-acdb-2dcfc`Array#forEach`73c0d96",
    Name: "Delhi"
  },
  {
    Id: "264d54cb-b104-48ed-91db-673327ae8d0e",
    Name: "rohit-auditor"
  },
  {
    Id: "ce9691b3-dc55-4d30-baf4-7987c2b49b3e",
    Name: "test"
  },
  {
    Id: "284e9e98-8ed7-4fb7-b09f-5d1f2a668b15",
    Name: "aman"
  }
]
var array2 = ["809cd136-02c7-4cc8-b9de-04fd3359b265", "609d3a78-8f7c-4843-acdb-2dcfc73c0d96"]

var add = {
  status: true
};

var newArray = array1.map(o => array2.includes(o.Id) ? {...o,  ...add} : { ...add })

console.log(newArray);
```

---

If you want to update the original array then simply iterate over the array using [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method and add an additional property using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) if necessary.

```
array1.forEach(o => array2.includes(o.Id) && Object.assign(o,add))
```

```js
var array1 = [{
    Id: "809cd136-02c7-4cc8-b9de-04fd3359b265",
    Name: "testing"
  },
  {
    Id: "609d3a78-8f7c-4843-acdb-2dcfc73c0d96",
    Name: "Delhi"
  },
  {
    Id: "264d54cb-b104-48ed-91db-673327ae8d0e",
    Name: "rohit-auditor"
  },
  {
    Id: "ce9691b3-dc55-4d30-baf4-7987c2b49b3e",
    Name: "test"
  },
  {
    Id: "284e9e98-8ed7-4fb7-b09f-5d1f2a668b15",
    Name: "aman"
  }
]
var array2 = ["809cd136-02c7-4cc8-b9de-04fd3359b265", "609d3a78-8f7c-4843-acdb-2dcfc73c0d96"]

var add = {
  status: true
};

array1.forEach(o => array2.includes(o.Id) && Object.assign(o, add))

console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `map` & `indexOf` will be enough

```
var array1 = [
    {Id: "809cd136-02c7-4cc8-b9de-04fd3359b265", Name: "testing"},
    {Id: "609d3a78-8f7c-4843-acdb-2dcfc73c0d96", Name: "Delhi"},
    {Id: "264d54cb-b104-48ed-91db-673327ae8d0e", Name: "rohit-auditor"},
    {Id: "ce9691b3-dc55-4d30-baf4-7987c2b49b3e", Name: "test"},
    {Id: "284e9e98-8ed7-4fb7-b09f-5d1f2a668b15", Name: "aman"}
    ] 

    var array2 = ["809cd136-02c7-4cc8-b9de-04fd3359b265", "609d3a78-8f7c-4843-acdb-2dcfc73c0d96"]


    var result=array1.map(el=>{

        if(array2.indexOf(el.Id)>-1){
        el.status=true
      }
      return el
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare element of `second array` with `id's of element of first array` and add key `(status)` to those matching found.

```js
var array1 = [{Id: "809cd136-02c7-4cc8-b9de-04fd3359b265",Name: "testing"},{Id: "609d3a78-8f7c-4843-acdb-2dcfc73c0d96", Name: "Delhi"},{Id: "264d54cb-b104-48ed-91db-673327ae8d0e", Name: "rohit-auditor"},{Id: "ce9691b3-dc55-4d30-baf4-7987c2b49b3e", Name: "test"},{Id: "284e9e98-8ed7-4fb7-b09f-5d1f2a668b15", Name: "aman"}]; 
var array2 = ["809cd136-02c7-4cc8-b9de-04fd3359b265", "609d3a78-8f7c-4843-acdb-2dcfc73c0d96"];

array2.forEach(function(secondElem) {
   let matchingElemInFirstArr = array1.find(el=>el.Id==secondElem);
   matchingElemInFirstArr ['status']=true;
 });

console.log(array1);
```